# Como alinha o formulário em bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Não estou conseguindo alinha o formulário, será que alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalJustificar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
     <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Justificar Remessa</h4>
                    </div>
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="AdministracaoRemessa!cadastrar" method="post">    
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><fmt:message key="label.isso.um.leibol" /></label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                         <select id="comboPessoaJuridica" name="variavel.metodo" class="form-control select2">
                                                <option value ="">-</option>
                                                    <c:forEach items="${listadeObjetos.nomeDaentidade}" var="PJ">
                                                <option value="${fn:replace(PJ.codigo,'.','')}">${PJ.nome}</option>
                                           </c:forEach>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                <div class="row">    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Período</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 input-altura">
                            <input id="idVersaoProcesso" type="text" class="form-control" 
                                name="historicoRemessa.motivo" value=""/>
                        </div>
                            a
                    <div class="col-sm-2 input-altura">
                        <input id="idVersaoProcesso" type="text" class="form-control" 
                            name="historicoRemessa.motivo" value=""/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Motivo</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-3 input-altura">
                         <input id="idVersaoProcesso" type="text" class="form-control" 
                            name="historicoRemessa.motivo" value=""/>
                     </div>
               </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar"/>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Isso é a imagem em tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que acontece é que **Unidade Jurisdicionada** deveria está tudo na minha linha juntamente com o listebox.
O **Periodo** com o textbox deveria está alinhado com o **Motivo** junto com o textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cara seu código está tão bagunçado que nem valia a pena mexer, era `div` sem fechar, `modal` sem o `modal-body`, `form` fechando com o `modal-footer` dentro... uma bagunça... por isso fiz esse modelo do zero.

O seu principal problema é que a `label` que vc está usando é muito maior que a coluna, ai ele quebra a linha e empurra a `col` seguinte mais para baixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu criei uma classe chamada `pt-0`, ela significa que a `label` vai ter `padding-top 0`, e essa pequena diferença já foi o suficiente para alinhar. Existem outras formas para tratar isso, mas acredito que essa é a que pode te atender melhor e é bem simples de fazer.

Segue o código da imagem acima

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <style>
    .pt-0 {
      padding-top: 0 !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- <div class="modal fade" id="modalJustificar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> -->
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Justificar Remessa</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="AdministracaoRemessa!cadastrar" method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label pt-0">uma label maior que a coluna</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar" />
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```